# Borderlands 2-Gun help

Tags: borderlands-2

In Borderlands 2 when you have a gun with example (390x13+11% DMG boost = 5627.7) DMG and having a gun with (612x7 = 4284) and having another gun do (533x10 = 5330) is the first gun which has the lowest DMG but highest multiplier better then the 612 and 533? Does the maths in this game work like this or is the 612 still better? Cause compare wise in game it saysthe 612 is better not taking the multiplier into effect